# Chaining Angular filters in controller while making them variable

Tags: angularjs, filter

Say I create an Angular app and write some new filters: Show only `odd`s, and show only `lucky` numbers.

There's an `oddList` filter and a `luckyList` filter:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.filter('oddList', function() {
    return function(items) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            if (item % 2 !== 0)
                filtered.push(item);
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
app.filter('luckyList', function() {
    return function(items) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            if (item === 2 || item === 7 || item === 11)
                filtered.push(item);
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

In the view portion, I can chain these filters:

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="number in numbers | oddList | luckyList">{$number}</li></ul>
```

When this works, I should see `7` and `11` remaining.

**I want to make my filters *variable* for this `ng-repeat`.** Is there something I can do that's similar to this process?

Say I name the variable filter `filter:listFilter` so that in our controller, we can dynamically update `$scope.listFilter`.

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="number in numbers | filter:listFilter">{$number}</li></ul>
```

And the controller with pseudo code:

```
app.controller('main', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
    $scope.listFilter = $filter('oddList | luckyList');
});
```

Any idea how I could chain (variable) filters in the controller? Would like to be able to toggle between just odd, just lucky and/or both.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xesued/Bw77D/7/ closest example i've seen..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An approach is to use a function to return the filtered data:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

    $scope.filteredNumbers = function() {
        var result = $scope.numbers;

        if ($scope.oddListEnabled) {
            result = $filter('oddList')(result);  
        }        
        if ($scope.luckyListEnabled) {    
            result = $filter('luckyList')(result);
        }

        return result;
    };
}
```

And the template:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="number in filteredNumbers()">
    {{number}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4ectDA?p=preview

Comment: gorgeous! didn't even consider using a function as the ng-repeat data provider. Thanks

Comment: But is it possible to do something like `<li ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{{selectedFilter}}">` and a `<select ng-model="selectedFilter">`, so the filter changes automaticaly?

Comment: Yes, @ViniciusPires you can also define custom filters:
'<li ng-repeat="num in numbers | filteredNumbers:enabledList">'
by using ":", you can pass new arguments into the function:
'
filter('filteredNumbers', function () {
    return function filteredNumbers (numbers, enabledList) {};
});
'

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't make myself clear enough... I was asking if it is possible to change the filter at runtime, setting a new value to the filter from a controller or a direct data-bind... By this time I figured out that it's possible to make what I said with just a little change: `<li ng-repeat="product in products | filter:selectedFilter">`... So it is possible to set the value of `$scope.selectedFilter` to `{ name: 'Coke' }` or `{ category: 'Soda'}`, depending of what is selected by the user in the combo `<select ng-model="selectedFilter">`... Just sharing :)